# Flutter BlocConsumer react only to certain state property changes

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-bloc

Is it possible in Bloc, inside a BlocConsumer to only redraw a Widget when certain
subset of properties of the Bloc's state change

I want the "buildWhen" in one screen to return true only if 3 props changed and in another screen i have another BlocConsumer that will be rebuilt if any property of the state changes.

My reckon so far is, I can only do this by splitting the bloc into several ones with different states.

thanks.

Comment: you simply put some conditions or constraints as some parameter changed of a state then only return the widget you wanna rebuild. rather bifurcating the blocs would be the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to achieve this.

#### 1. [Bloc consumer with buildWhen](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocconsumer)

We use build when to tell the bloc consumer/builder that we it needs to rebuild the widget based on specific things changed between `previous` and `current` state.

ex.:

```
BlocBuilder<TestBloc, TestState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    return Text(
      '${state.a + state.b + state.c + state.d}',
    );
  },
  buildWhen: (previous, current) {
    return previous.a != current.a ||
        previous.b != current.b ||
        previous.c != current.c;
  },
),
```

in this example widget will only be built again when a, b, or c change.

#### 2. [BlocSelector](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocselector)

BlocSelector is the widget used for listening and consuming specific parts of the bloc. So when we need to use only 3 parameters of the state we can have this example:

```
BlocSelector<TestBloc, TestState, int>(
  selector: (state) {
    return state.a + state.b + state.c;
  },
  builder: (context, abcState) {
    return Text('Updated value is: $abcState');
  },
),
```

These two different approaches have different use cases.

The **1st** approach (build when) is used when you want the whole state in the builder function and your widget, but you want the widget to rebuild only when certain parts of the state is changed.

The **2nd** approach (bloc selector) is used when you want to use specific parameters of the bloc for a widget render, and also this widget should not be built again if other parts of bloc get updated.